# Comparing two Lists of Type Product

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Both List A and List B are of type Products

```
 List A = new List();
 List B = new List();
```

For the sake of simplicity, I have mentioned the Products in each List. The numbers here are referring to the Product ID.

List A contains 1,2,3,4,5

List B contains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

I want to know the code in c# asp.net that will compare the two lists, and synchronizing them. Meaning if List B had some more Products (lets say 19,20) it copy 19,20 to List A.

How would I compare the qty attribute. I have to check if the same product ID is in both lists.If one from List B is different from List A, then it would check the qty attribute. It would synch them both. (FROM LIST B TO LIST A)

Secondly if I delete a Product from B, (say 3), it should be also deleted from List A.

Whatever I do in List B (is is new session), it must be synchronized to List A.
That includes adding new product, removing, and updating the quantity of a specific product.

Comment: Sounds like a design issue to begin with

Comment: ... and then like a well-phrased "please send the code" question. What did you try?

Comment: for your information i have already spent 3 hours trying to get it working.....

Comment: @user478636: Then show us what you did in those 3 hours. Otherwise we might provide answers without knowing they're things you tried. Then time is wasted. And nothing gets solved. And no one is happy.

Comment: @user478636 for your information try to read more about design patterns

Comment: at user47..  : ok, but let us know what you have tried than, and you will be helped further here, it's probably a oneliner for lots of guys here... Anyway : a design issue does not mean I dont want to help you..   When so. asks me : how do you use a screwdriver to nail this?  It might be better to tell them to use a hammer than to answer quick 'turn it around and use the handle'

Comment: actually i am synchronizing between the session of a shopping cart, and the cart items in the database. i first load the results from db and save it to a session.....then after user logs out...i want to save the session to the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If List B is always going to win, why would you bother synchronising?

```
ListA.Clear();
ListA.AddRange(ListB.Items);
```

Answer (score 0):

In summary:

- Sort both lists.
- Declare two indexers
- loop while indexers are less than the length of their respective lists
- Use a comparer to tell if the items at the current indexes are the same.
- Build logic that adds or removes an item from the destination list based on the comparer result
- Increment your indexers as appropriate based on previous action

You will likely have to spend a bit of time tweaking said code to get it working correctly but that is the general process.

Another alternative would be to just clear the second list and add all of the items from the first list.

The "best" approach is highly dependent on what you are doing and why.

Comment: That's my point : the best approach in 99% is not maintaining 2 lists to begin with.

Comment: @peter The times I have used this type of structure involved a data caching scheme for a web app. List A was part of the cache, list B was an update that needed to be reflected in the cache. Basically I was after an incremental update of the data in the cache.  At this point I am assuming the OP is attempting something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make your `ListA` and `ListB` as `ObservableCollection` of `Product`. Then write code in the `CollectionChanged` event handlers.